# Websphere admin console not working

Tags: java, console, websphere, admin, rad

I have trouble opening the admin console for the websphere server. The server is up and running though, the application deployed and all. The only problem is with the console which gives a 404 error. Does anyone know how to fix this? Maybe reinstall/restore the console somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know which port the console is running on? Also, is the console application running? Did somebody shut down or uninstall it? Have you tried to reboot the server?

Comment: Hi! How can I check if the console app is running? Thanks!

Comment: well...you kind of need the console to see it....:). But that is why I was wondering if you tried a reboot. Before I go any further....I noticed you tagged this "rad". Does this mean the admin console for a WAS server in your RAD installation? Or are you meaning a standalone installation of WAS?

Comment: What does netstat tell you? Do you have listening processes on 9060 and 9043? Are you trying to access /ibm/console/ ?

Comment: thanks everyone! there's still some problem when trying to open the console from RAD...cause for some reason it's port changed and RAD can't find it. I managed to open it from my browser though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check and make sure the DMGR is up and running on the primary node.  Start --> Run --> Services.msc.  Look for something that looks like "IBM WebSphere Application Server V6.1 - CellManager01" and ensure it is running.  If not, browse to the installation location of Websphere "AppServer\profiles\Dmgr01\logs\dmgr" and look in the Systemout.log and the SystemErr.log for details.  Also look in the "AppServer\profiles\Dmgr01\logs\ffdc" directory.

Comment: thanks for the tips! the server is up and running! I sort of found the problem though!

Comment: what if you are not using a DMGR, whats the solution?

Answer (score 7):

You can try to reinstall the admin console :

Goto C:\[PATH TO PROFILE]\bin

Then run the Jython commands, first to cleanup, then to reinstall :

```
wsadmin -lang jython -f deployConsole.py remove
```

Wait till the admin-console is uninstalled.

Now reinstall of administrative console (isclite) will complete without errors (hopefully)

```
wsadmin -lang jython -f deployConsole.py install
```

Admin console should work now.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. I was able to solve it by:

1. Deleting the existing profile
2. Creating a new profile
3. Running the WAS in RAD with that newly created profile

Profile management :- 
Method :- RAD -> windows > prefereneces > server > websphere application server > selecting the websphere server 7.0 > click the run profile management tool button in the bottom section.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this before trying to delete the new profile. I had this same problem where console was not coming up. I closed the RAD and re-opened it but didnt work. Go to Window --> Reset Perspective and then go to show view and get the console.
If still you cant see the console, go to customize perspective and click general and enable console. 
If this doesnt work then only delete and recreate profile.